Can't run the Jhipster project because npm error code ERR_INVALID_URL
I run my Jhipster project using ./gradlew and it's getting error like below. It's also happened when I firstly generate project using jhipster command.
> Task :npmSetup FAILED
npm error code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm error Invalid URL

The full link gradle scans : https://scans.gradle.com/s/ixqii6xdhzxbi
I have tried to

reinstalling the nodejs
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
delete the npm config proxy as well
make sure the environment variables path is in the correct place

but it's still getting the same error
Do you have any idea what's the solution? I'm stuck in this error
Version information:
Jhipster 8.6,
Nodejs 20.16.0,
npm 10.8.1,
Java 17.0.10

Are you able to try it on another machine, or perhaps with Gitpod? If you can push it to a GitHub repo, Gitpod makes it easy to open and run.

@MattRaible yes, i have tried to run it in linux and it works fine. also it works in the another computer. I think it may have something to do with my local environment, but I'm out of ideas at this point
